# Demandware site testing

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, performance-testing

We are using Demandware for our eCommerce site so they are giving sandboxes for development and testing.

I am automating the site for regression testing. But if I run automation scripts on Testing sandbox, sometimes it is taking longer time to load the page as a result test fails.

So what is the best way to do automation testing on Demandware related websites ?

Is it possible to deploy site to Cloud ?

Is is possible to increase the performance of testing related sandbox ? So tests will not fail?

Can you please suggest your thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use development instance for these tests, as it is close to production in terms that it uses Akamai CDN, so the loading of pages will be relatively faster.
If sandboxes/development instances are performing slow, it may be good idea to look in Pipeline profiler in Demandware Business Manager to get insight as to where the performance bottleneck is lying.